# num_threads clause not setting number of threads

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following simple program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp>

int main() {

    std::cout << "max threads: " << omp_get_max_threads() << "\n";

    #pragma parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        std::cout << "Hello from " << tid << " of " << omp_get_num_threads() << "\n";

        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            std::cout << "(" << tid << ", " << i << ")\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And I am compiling with `clang++ -fopenmp=libomp main.cpp`. I am able to compile and run other OpenMP programs compiled in this way.

I would expect the `num_threads(4)` to cause the parallel region to run across 4 threads. Instead I experience the following output:

```
max threads: 4
Hello from 0 of 1
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
```

Why is the parallel region not running across 4 threads?

Comment: Please compile your code with `-Wall`. `#pragma parallel` -> `#pragma omp parallel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left the `omp` out of your `parallel` pragma.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
```